# NoMethodError - undefined method `by_email' for ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::BlackList:Class:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have an email_address object that I am trying to check to see if it is on the blacklist for that particular domain. I'm calling it like this:

```
elsif @email.blacklisted?(@domain.id)
  do something ...
end
```

I am getting the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `by_email' for ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::BlackList:Class:
```

I have also tried doing a .find_all_by_id instead of using the blacklist scopes I created. Same error though. This is driving me crazy, any ideas would be amazing!

EmailAddress Class

```
class EmailAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :global_blacklist

  has_many :transactions
  has_many :black_lists
  has_many :opt_outs

  validates :email, :presence => true,
          :uniqueness => true
  validates :global_blacklist, :acceptance => true

  def blacklisted?(domain_id)
    black_lists = BlackList.by_email(self.id).by_domain(domain_id)

    black_lists.count > 0
  end
end
```

BlackList Class

```
class BlackList < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :domain_id, :email_address_id, :date_added

  belongs_to :domain
  belongs_to :email_address

  validates :domain_id, :presence => true
  validates :email_address_id, :presence => true
  validates :date_added, :presence => true

  GLOBAL_BLACK_LIST_THRESHOLD = 2

  scope :by_domain, ->(domain_id) { where('domain_id = ?', domain_id) }
  scope :by_email, ->(email_id) { where('email_address_id = ?', email_id) }


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this problem...

The class name BlackList (capitol L) seems to be an ActiveModel Class Name.

I changed the class name to Blacklist (one word instead of two) and the problem went away.